# make a function of textbox with parameters string

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a function of it. Do you think it is possible? that is, not to have to write this code hundreds of times.

```
Dim pieces() As String = Textbox1.Text.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Dim str As String = ""

        For Each piece As String In pieces
            str &= String.Join(",", piece.ToCharArray().ToList()) & ControlChars.CrLf
        Next

        Textbox2.Text = str
```

Comment: You want a comma between every character in each line?

Comment: yes, i want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `Function` you need a return type, in this case `String` and a `Return` statement.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str = AddCommas(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = str
End Sub

Private Function AddCommas(inputString As String) As String
    Dim pieces() As String = inputString.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim str As String = ""
    For Each piece As String In pieces
        str &= String.Join(",", piece.ToCharArray().ToList()) & ControlChars.CrLf
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```